# How to add a contribution in activity move ring in apple watch using third party app

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, healthkit

We have an app with a feature like a get real-time workout data via Bluetooth—including strides, distance, calories burned, active time, and more.

We have also integrated the Health app so we are able to write/read data easily (i.e Active energy, Steps and Walking + Running distance) in the Health app.

Now our question is Apple health is recording steps from our app but these steps are not making it watch activity rings.

**Is there any way to reflect our workout data in an apple watch activity ring (move ring)?**

Currently, Our app is made for iPhone, Do we need to create a watch app for that?

Please suggest any solution if have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Using Workout Samples | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/using_workout_samples#2961963):

> ## Filling the Rings
>
> Workout samples can contribute to the Move and Exercise rings in the Activity app. To contribute, you must associate one or more active energy burned samples with the workout. Additionally:
>
> - **In watchOS.** Use a workout session to track the user’s activity. When the session has ended, create a workout object and the associated active energy burned samples. For more information, see [HKWorkoutSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutsession). The system updates the Move ring based on the active energy burned samples. It updates the Exercise ring based on the amount of time the user spent actually exerting themselves during the workout session, as calculated by the watch’s sensors.
> - **In iOS 10 or later.** No additional work is necessary. Workout objects automatically contribute to both the Move and Exercise rings. The Exercise ring is increased by the workout’s total duration, and the Move ring is increased by the number of calories in the associated active energy burned samples. HealthKit also increases the Stand ring by one hour for each wall-clock hour that the workout overlaps.
> - **In iOS 9.** Workout objects saved on iPhone do not contribute to the activity rings.
>
> Create and save workouts on the device that makes the most sense for your application. This will typically be the device that is running the logic for the user's workout.

Comment: @Austing So for that do we need to create an apple watch app?

Comment: @pradipsutariya You don't need to for iOS 10 or later, but you need to if you're supporting iOS 9.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm preparing a demo project for more surety.

Comment: @Austing do you have any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323810/apple-watch-not-displaying-my-fitness-app-data-on-exercise-minutes-ring-can-we?