# Apple Watch Exercise Minute ring being updated from workout start-end time not from the Duration

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-watch, healthkit

We have a Fitness app and we are writing fitness data to the Healthkit like Steps, Walking Running distance, and Active energy. and it is working as expected in the Health App

We also writing Workout data for Apple watch activity ring, we can show our data is reflected on the Apple Watch activity ring for Active Energy but **Exercise Minutes** ring being updated from workout start-end time not from the Duration

The problem here is the Exercise ring vs Actual exercise done.

Our app is sending the workout data to Apple Health every 30 minutes,  workout data contains the total distance, total energy burned, startDate, endDate, or duration properties.

So the app is sending the workout data for a 30 minutes time interval with the actual duration of the exercise done between the 30 minutes of interval.

Say for Eg: 30 minutes is the time interval(From 12:00 to 12.30) and actual exercise done between this duration is say 01:32 minutes.

The Move ring here shows actual data that our app writes but the Exercise ring shows different data than our app writes.

The Exercise ring here should show 1/30 instead of 30/30.

Here Excercise ring considers the total workout interval(30 Minutes)but not considered the total time(01:32 minutes Actual Duration)to create the Excercise Ring.

[image]t

I've followed this [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/adding_samples_to_a_workout) to create a workout sample for the Activity ring

So my question is, is there a way by which the Apple Watch activity ring can display my app data(exercise duration) on the Exercise Minutes ring?

For reference, I've attached a screenshot and highlighted the Excercise portion on the same.
[image]

Comment: You state _"not for **Exercise Minutes**"_, but that is the green ring that displays 238 minutes (roughly 4 full revolutions). So what do you believe is incorrect?

Comment: @PDK I've added more information to the Question, Could you please have a look at the question again?

Comment: Are you following [all the steps here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkout#2961963)?

Comment: @Coder-256 I've implemented it like this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/adding_samples_to_a_workout

Comment: I followed this method to create workout object
init(activityType: HKWorkoutActivityType, start: Date, end: Date, duration: TimeInterval, totalEnergyBurned: HKQuantity?, totalDistance: HKQuantity?, metadata: [String : Any]?)
Instantiates a new workout that includes the energy burned, distance, and metadata for the workout.

Comment: The docs say, the system "updates the Exercise ring based on the amount of time the user spent actually exerting themselves during the workout session, as calculated by the watch’s sensors", so I think you might need to use an actual `HKWorkoutSession`, live during the workout (though I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: @Coder-256 HKWorkoutSession would not help out in our case as we are storing physical workout data to Activity ring so

Comment: What do you mean? I am suggesting `HKWorkoutSession` because I think the watch wants to actually track heart rate, etc. using its own sensors during the workout in order to calculate the activity/green ring, then it will use the data you manually provide to help determine the move/red ring.

Comment: We have an elliptical device and we syncing all workout data to our Fitness app. Our app aggregate all workout data say for 30 minutes as I mentioned in the question and then writes the workout data to the Health app using the HKWorkout object. like this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/adding_samples_to_a_workout and the HKWorkobject, data can contribute to Apple Move and Exercise ring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226559/discussion-between-pradip-sutariya-and-coder-256).